# Value stored to '' during initialisation is never read

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the warning `Value stored to '' during initialisation is never read` when run Build and analyze tool.

Its telling on `stRs232Timer* pTimer = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));`

also i'm getting the same warning for `dwDelay=1000` at some part of the function.
which is declared as `unsigned long int dwDelay = 0;`

Why is it so?

Comment: What is telling you the analyser? Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you never use `pTimer`.

**Edit**
To clarify, it is actually telling you that you never use that particular value of pTimer.  If you assign it and then assign it again before using it, you will get the message. e.g.

```
 stRs232Timer* pTimer = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));

 // Lots of code not using pTimer.

 pTimer = someFunction();
```

will give that warning.

Comment: Its telling me "value stored to 'pTimer' during intialisation is never used".But i'm using it in my program.I could able read values from it.

Comment: @theodore: You are probably mistaken.  I think it's more likely that you are wrong than that the analyzer has a bug in it to cause this false positive.